# Sort Worksheets based on multiple cell values

Tags: excel, vba

[image]  This is a sample of K4 L4

[![enter image description here][2]][2]  This is a sample of K63

So again I want to arrange each worksheet in the workbook based on the values in K4, L4 and than K63

Hello I'm looking for a code that will sort the worksheets in the workbook based on multiple cell values.  First I will like to sort all worksheets in the workbook based on K4 (text Ascending Order) than by L4 (text Ascending Order) and finally by cell k63 (value greatest to least).  I'm struggling with the logic piece on how to make it vba go in sequence.  Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

I hid rows and delete sensitive data.  But from the screen shot you can basically get the jist of how I would like the worksheets arranged

Comment: When you say "sort Worksheets" you probably need to sort the used range in all worksheets. If so, your code should iterate between all workbook sheets and apply the same sorting to each. Now, please explain what do you understand by "based on K4, L4, k63"? On which row is the header, if any? Do you want sorting a range having a header, or not? Are you sure that you really mean sorting and not filtering? And, can you show us what you tried by yourself? We will maybe better understand what you really try accomplishing.

Comment: No I want to sort a workbook of about 100 worksheets based on the criteria that's present in each of those three cells.

Comment: For example  Sheet 1 has k4 = a l4 a and k63 64% while Sheet 2 has k4 = a and l4 = a and k63 = 68%  than move sheet 2 ahead of sheet 1.

Comment: No offence, but are you sure that you know what sorting means? `Sort` method does not have a `Criteria` parameter... Trying to better describe what you understand by sorting maybe will help us understanding what you really need accomplishing.

Comment: @user3666237, a sample data or a picture of their format would be much appreciated and maybe the desired output is necessary too since you can't describe accurately what you're looking for.

Comment: @FaneDuru No offense taking I seeking help bro no egos here.  I'm essentially trying to arrange or sort each worksheet in the workkbook based on the value in those cells but the sequential order I want the worksheets arrange is based on k4, l4 and than k63.  Each worksheet has values in those cells that i will like to arrange them by.  Hope thats clear

Comment: So you want to rearrange the worksheets in the workbook based on values of cells? So I would try to modify a sorting algorithm (bubble sort or quicksort) and move the worksheets.

Comment: @L'Artiste  just snap shot some pictures

Comment: @Shrotter not following every sort worksheet macro I ever used centered around one condition.  Never multiple so I'm running into trouble with the logic sequence in my code

Comment: So you want **rearranging the sheets position based on the mentioned cells value**?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes that is correct

Comment: @user3666237, can you give a screenshot of the input/output ?

Comment: OK. Now, please better explain what to be the rearranging algorithm. I mean the code should compare a sheet with the mentioned cells values of the next one. Now, if in case of the first 'criteria' the value in the following sheet is bigger, should the position changing take place without any comparation of the other two? I mean, the last one is taken in consideration **only if the previous two** matches. Would such an understanding be correct?

Comment: @FaneDuru So the first two cells are basically names.  So it arranging the worksheets in Order by the person name.  Lets say K4 = Ryan and L4 = Frank on a sheet 1 than on sheet 2 k4 = Ryan and L4 = Brown based on that sheet 2 should be ahead of sheet 1.  Than the last criteria kicks in which is basically a percentage.  So the Ryan/Brown combiantion can have about 25 worksheets spread out in the workbook.  Basically arrange those worksheets together than by the value in k63 arrange the workshets from k63 greatest to least

Comment: @L'Artiste I post a screenshot I hid rows so everything can fit ino the screen shot.  But basically I have over 100 worksheets I want to arrange first by the combination of K4, L4, than K63 greatest to least

Comment: I am afraid I still cannot get you... Based on what to move sheet 2 ahead? Should the next understanding be correct: **Find all unique combinations of  concatenated names in k4 and L4 and then arrange/sort this unique combinations (descending) related to k63 value**. Should such an understanding be correct? If so, based on what to also sort this unique combinations  groups?

Comment: @FaneDuru you might be on to something I never thought to concatenated the values that may work.  But after grouing the concatenated group of worksheets they should than be arranged by the value in k63.  Lets say for ex Sheet 1  has Ryan/Brown k63 98% Sheet 2 has Ryan/Brown k63 100 percent and sheet 3 has Ryan/Dog k63 100%.  The order should be sheet 2 than sheet 1 and finally sheet 3.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Not exactly, sorry... I would like to firstly clarify the grouping and **its** sorting issue. Is my above understanding correct, from this point of view? **Forget the way of obtaining the goal**... After having the 'Ryan/Brown' group sorted descending, let us, suppose that 'Ryan/Dog' should be analyzed from its place/position point of view. Being composed of only one case or many, where to be placed against 'Ryan/Brown' one? Before it, because of invers alphabetically sorting? (Dog > Brown)?

Comment: @FaneDuru I'll prefer alphabetically ascending for that part but if I can get the grouping down I can live with the result.  lets say ryan/brown has 10 sheets as long as those sheets are adjacent to each other to be thats the biggest challenge in a workbook with about 100 sheets and maybe 20 different combinations of the example we are describing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code shows how you could achieve this:

Create an array of objects that hold the information for every sheet, including the sheet name itself

Sort the array according to your needs. I have used a simple bubble sort as it is fast enough for 100 records - but if you want, feel free to look for more efficient sort algorithms, plenty around here on SO and elsewhere. The key of sorting is that you have a custom compare method that returns -1 if object 1 is "smaller" (needs to be sorted to the left) and 1 if it is "larger" - very similar to the `strComp`-method in VBA.

After sorting, use the sheet names of the sorted array to rearrange the sheets.

Create a class module and name it `clsSheetData` that holds the information needed for sorting.

```
Public sheetname As String
Public gmo As String
Public ovp As String
Public percent As Double
```

Create a regular module with the code (I assume you want to sort `ThisWorkbook`, else pass the workbook as parameter)

```
Sub SortSheets()
    ' Define the array
    ReDim arr(1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) As clsSheetData
    ' - - Step 1: Build array with data
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set arr(ws.Index) = New clsSheetData
        arr(ws.Index).sheetname = ws.Name
        arr(ws.Index).gmo = ws.Range("K4")
        arr(ws.Index).ovp = ws.Range("L4")
        arr(ws.Index).percent = ws.Range("K63")
    Next
    
    ' - - Step 2: Sort Array (Bubblesort)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
            If sheetCompare(arr(i), arr(j)) > 0 Then
                Dim Temp As clsSheetData
                Set Temp = arr(j)
                Set arr(j) = arr(i)
                Set arr(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ' - - Step3: Rearrange sheets
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        With ThisWorkbook
            .Sheets(arr(i).sheetname).Move before:=.Sheets(i)
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Function sheetCompare(o1 As clsSheetData, o2 As clsSheetData) As Integer
    ' Compare the data of 2 sheets. 
    If o1.gmo <> o2.gmo Then      ' If gmo is different, use that as criteria
        sheetCompare = StrComp(o1.gmo, o2.gmo, vbTextCompare)
    ElseIf o1.ovp <> o2.ovp Then  ' Else If ovp is different, use that as criteria
        sheetCompare = StrComp(o1.ovp, o2.ovp, vbTextCompare)
    Else                          ' Else, compare percentage 
        sheetCompare = IIf(o1.percent > o2.percent, -1, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: when running it I get the error message Compile error:  User-defined type not defined  also the below function the workbook has about 150 sheets I just said two sheets as an example

Comment: a) If you get the user-defined type error, you didn't create the class module or you didn't named it correctly. b) The code will sort *any* number of sheets of a workbook.

Comment: I don't know you lol but I will love to buy you a beer you have no idea how much time you saved me Thank you so much